# How to set button background drawable image with ripple effect in android

Tags: android, background, android-drawable, ripple

My Xml code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/link_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/google_btn" />
```

I am applying Default ripple effect

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/link_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />
```

but I need button background `"@drawable/google_btn"` with
`"?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`. it's means i need  ripple effect with custom background.

Comment: How can i do that one

Comment: It is worth stressing out that (as @zahidul mentioned), ripple effects are for Android v21 and above only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your `drawable-v21` folder you can write code for ripple effect by your own. Make a drawable xml file and set starting tag by `ripple`. Like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="@color/colorAccentDark">
    <item>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <item
                android:drawable="@color/button_accent_dark"
                android:state_checked="false"/>
            <item
                android:drawable="@color/button_accent"
                android:state_checked="true" />
            <item
                android:drawable="@color/button_accent_dark" />

        </selector>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Comment: Thank you @Zahidul Islam.. That is working  and one more Doubt how can I apply ripple effects on below V21

Answer (score 10):

When the button has a background from the drawable, we can add ripple effect to the foreground parameter.. Check below code its working for my button with a different background

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"                                                             
android:background="@drawable/shape_login_button"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true"
android:text="@string/action_button_login"
 />
```

Add below parameter for ripple effect

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_rectangle"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_rect_states"/>

</ripple>
```

Try the above code here in drawables give your own custom drawable backgrounds as you need it.

Comment: Thats great below v21 ripple dont work so there you eed to create selector file of your button states for normal and for pressed state @PrithivDharmaraj.. Kindly accept or upvote if my answer helps you..

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to create a layer list drawable and set that as a background. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_background"/>
    <item android:drawable="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
</layer-list>
```